# Waiting function for CSS element in Capybara

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, selenium-chromedriver, capybara-webkit

There are waiting and non-waiting functions in Capybara. I am trying to use the first as much as possible.

Is there a way to use `find` (or one of its derivatives) to look for a CSS element that appears asynchronously?
Unfortunately, function `page.has_css?` is a non-waiting function.

Comment: The method `find` already waits for the element to be found. Since a test should not contain any logic, you should use `page.assert_selector('#foo', :count => 1)` to wait for an element or  `page.assert_selector('#foo', :count => 0)` to wait for none.

Comment: @FlorentB. `page.assert_selector('#foo', :count => 0)` would normally be written `page.assert_no_selector('#foo')`, which can also handle situations like "ensure there aren't 3 matching elements" - `page.assert_no_selector('#foo', count: 3)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your claim that `page.has_css?` is a non-waiting function is not correct.  `page.has_css?` will wait up to `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` seconds for an element to appear on the page and return `true` or `false` based on whether or not the element is on the page within that time.  Therefore, given `Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5`

```
if page.has_css?("div#my_div")
   puts "on page"
else
   puts "not on page"
end
```

will wait for up to 5 seconds. As soon as a div with id of "my_div" is visible on the page it will print "on page".  If a matching div doesn't become visible within 5 seconds it will print "not on page".  If you want it to wait longer for a specific call you can override `default_max_wait_time` by passing the `:wait` option

```
if page.has_css?("div#my_div", wait: 10)  # will wait up to 10 seconds
  ...
```

If rather than wanting a boolean response you want to ensure the element exists you can do any of

```
page.assert_selector(:css, 'div#my_div') # :css is the default so can usually be omitted
page.assert_css('div#my_div') # minitest
expect(page).to have_css('div#my_div') # RSpec
```

which will wait for the element to appear as previously, but raise an exception rather than returning `false` if the element does not appear

If you need the actual element you can use `find` which will also wait.  So

```
el = page.find(:css, 'div#my_div') # :css is the default and can usually be omitted
```

will wait for the element to appear and return the element when found.  If the element is not found within `default_max_wait_time` seconds it will raise an exception.

Note: Basically, the only non-waiting methods are `all` and `first` and even those can be made to wait if you pass in any of the count options (`:count`, `:minimum`, `:maximum`, `:between`), although the elements returned from them would still be non-reloadable and can therefore have further behavior effects if used for scoping, etc.  Even methods like `click_link`, `click_button`, etc will wait since they are implemented as `find(...).click`, etc